# Handling unexpected exceptions on scala Futures

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

When using some code like the following:

```
scala> Future { null } onComplete { case Success(v) => v.toString }
```

Scala throws the following exception:

```
scala> java.lang.NullPointerException
    at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:11)
    at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:11)
    at     scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at     scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$3.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:107)
    at     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at     scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

This would be OK, since I am not handling any exceptions. The problem is that my application hangs completely.

I am using `concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` and I think `onComplete` is executed in this global execution context. The problem is that it seems like the execution context stops accepting any work and and the application just hangs.

Do I have to explicitly use `try ... catch` so that I protect my app in case something unexpected happens in `onComplete`?

Thank you

Comment: Can you just perform the potentially unsafe operation in the context of the future? E.g. `Future(null).map(_.toString).onComplete { ... }`.

Comment: Causing a null pointer exception was just the way I found to cause an exception without explicitly using `throw`. I don't' really have a 'pontentially unsafe' operation, everything I have inside my `onComplete` clause is code that could cause an exception..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, this was an issue only in the very earliest implementation.

You can supply a handler or "reporter":

```
scala> import util._
import util._

scala> import concurrent._
import concurrent._

scala> ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(null, (t: Throwable) => println(s"Hi, $t"))
res0: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutor = scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl@221a3fa4

scala> implicit val x = res0
x: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutor = scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl@221a3fa4

scala> Future { null } onComplete { case Success(v) => v.toString }
<console>:16: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: Failure(_)
              Future { null } onComplete { case Success(v) => v.toString }
                                         ^
Hi, java.lang.NullPointerException

scala>
```

Everything is handled.

Comment: I still have the same problem, the application hangs, just the exception is reported differently, with "Hi, <something>".. thanks

Comment: What I meant was, your callback is already wrapped in a try, that will call your reporter. What scala version, and are you sure it's not application-level deadlock?  Do a thread dump to check on what the pool is working on.

Comment: You are right. Since onComplete runs on a different executor, if it fails, my actor does not throw an exception and does not die, so the supervisor never restarts it so my app goes into a deadlock.. I found that using `map` and `recover` works much better since all exceptions both inside the future execution and the map callback are handled in `recover`. thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `NullPointerException` you get has nothing to do with the future; it does not happen inside the `Future` block.

What you can do, is wrapping code that might return `null` in [`Option()`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option$@apply[A]%28x:A%29:Option[A]).
Your code would then look like this:

```
Future { Option(mightBeANull) } onComplete { case Success(v) => v.map(_.toString) }
```

Comment: That would fix the problem of an unexpected null value but doesn't all the exception that might occurr inside my `onComplete` callback.. Using a `NullPointerException` was just an example

Comment: @simao: What happens inside the `onComplete` block has nothing to do with the exception, it's thus up to you to handle it the way you want.