# Exception causes Future to never complete

Tags: scala

Given the following code:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1))

val f = Future[Unit](throw new java.lang.InternalError())(ec)
```

The future `f` never completes. `f.value` is always `None`.

There was a known bug in scala-2.10 that was fixed:

http://mandubian.com/2013/02/22/scala-future-fatal-exception

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7029

I am on scala-2.11.

The example from the bug report uses NotImplementedErorr, which is correctly handled by the Future and it will complete. However, if I use InternalError as in my example above, then the Future never completes. This is true whether I use the ExecutionContext.global, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor, or Executors.newFixedThreadPool.

I can catch Throwable in the body of the Future and re-throw it with an exception wrapped around it that I know the Future will handle correctly, but that's a terrible solution.

Is this a known issue? Expected behavior? What options do I have to get sane behavior out of my Futures?

Comment: I can't find any documentation on this being intentional, but this behavior only seems to happen for Throwable subtypes that are not themselves subtypes of Exception

Answer (score 11):

From the source of [Future](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Future.scala).

```
override def run() = {
  promise complete {
    try Success(body) catch { case NonFatal(e) => Failure(e) }
  }
}
```

As you can see, `Future` is only catching `NonFatal` exception.

And the following is what [NonFatal](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/util/control/NonFatal.scala) matches.

```
def apply(t: Throwable): Boolean = t match {
  // VirtualMachineError includes OutOfMemoryError and other fatal errors
  case _: VirtualMachineError | _: ThreadDeath | _: InterruptedException | _: LinkageError | _: ControlThrowable => false
  case _ => true
```

}

Since [java.lang.InternalError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InternalError.html) is subclass of  `VirtualMachineError`, the thread which is running the task is just killed by exception, and the promise will never be completed.

From the overview of the [exceptions in the future](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#exceptions)

> Fatal exceptions (as determined by NonFatal) are rethrown in the thread executing the failed asynchronous computation. This informs the code managing the executing threads of the problem and allows it to fail fast, if necessary. See NonFatal for a more precise description of the semantics.

Therefore I think this is intended behavior.

Comment: Yes, it is clearly intended behavior to have the exception rethrown in the thread, but it seems an oversight that this causes the Future to never complete. The user is required to ensure that anything waiting on the Future get notified of the failure through some other mechanism.

Comment: @pheaver I don't think `Future` should be notified when the fatal error occurs. That should be the job for executor.  However, there's a long discussion for the current `Future`'s behavior https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/45ianF2rQYQ. Since StackOverflow is not a site to discuss, I think you should post a question to scala forum.

Comment: @pheaver also you can supply reporter as the second argument of `ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(null, reporter)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709602/handling-unexpected-exceptions-on-scala-futures , however not seems to work for fixed thread pool